# Why my buildozer not working well with my Kivymd app?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I tried five times to convert `.py` made with Kivymd to apk using Buildozer, but it always crash or close immediately or not even installed.

My buildzoer.spec changes:

```
title = My Custom App
package.name = myapp
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,requests # I didn't include json module because it's python standard module
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,otf,ttf
icon_filename = %(source.dir)s/data/myIcon.png # My icon is in same directory with main.py
osx.kivy_version = 1.11.1
```

It never gives me an error. Just debugged well and not worked in my Android phone.

Where I went wrong? (It worked well when I tried with Kivy sample app in kivy.org)

I'm using Python 3.8.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [logcat](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform) to get more details about the error.

Comment: In your link, it says I have to ‘Connect device to your computer and run adb logcat’ But what is RUN means? Also, is there any way to do this with some Logcat reader apps in Play store?

Comment: There are logcat apps but I guess they need root access. You can use a logcat software in your pc, have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=O_ROwKkd0aA). It will be much better than that.

Comment: How to open [this](https://imgur.com/a/6oDjBFL) JAR file? In video, he clicked .jar file and program opened, but how to do it? (I'm using Window 10)

Comment: You can't run builder on windows right. So you must be using ubuntu or something. Open in that

Comment: OK, now I finally see the logs. And it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'`. How I can solve this?

Comment: just add `urllib3` in the requirements of your `buildozer.spec` file

Comment: Now, I built by apk file, but now logcat gives me `requests: Max retries` error(My app uses requests module), so I add `time.sleep` in my app, then it is not even install. Why this happens?

Comment: time.sleep doesn't work in kivy. You have to use kivy.Clock for that. Now coming over to max retries error then most probably your app might not be able to connect to internet reason can be missing `INTERNET` permission. Make sure in yout buildozer.spec file you have `INTERNET` permission uncommented

Comment: Now, finally my app built without any error, but my app appears at left-down side, very small. And I set my window size in my code to (400, 700). This means I have to test all window size to make fit my app in my phone? Also I think if my window size gets bigger, then I thinks size of widgets must be get bigger too. Is there any way to get size of screen and change all size of window and widgets?

Comment: Just don't add Window.size it will automatically resize.